# Is it possible to get notified when a tag containing a certain commit is pushed?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to get notified if a specific commit or merge made it into release tagged x.y.z
is it possible to do this in gitlab or do i need to write a git hook script?

Answer (score 0):

GitLab has a webpage on enabling emails by push, You can use this for branch commits.
More information in the GitLab documentation, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee///////user/project/integrations/emails_on_push.html

On merge requests, you would also need to enable this.
More information in the GitLab documentation,
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/notifications.html#notifications-on-issues-merge-requests-and-epics

Comment: thanks for your answer but i'm searching for an option to only get notified when tag x.y.z including commit (or merge) 123abc is pushed. i edited the question for clarity.